# How can I build multiple android apps from the same project

Tags: android, cordova, telerik, android-manifest, icenium

We are using telerik AppBuilder which is built on top of PhoneGap. We are using the same project code with different configurations to create 3 apps. Basically AppBuilder project is the same, then we just change seeome css styles, images and some API connections and build it as 3 separate apps. For Android we have an issue. When we manually install 1 app, other apps cannot be installed. I get "Application not installed error on android". Once it is uninstalled, installation of another app succeeds. I guess ID needs to change somewhere. iOS works fine as I build it using 3 separate provision profiles. I changed app name for each app in manifest file  and also create a unique app id in project properties->general. I also tried hard-coding "package" property of manifest tag in manifest file to make sure it is unique. DB name is the same for all apps, I wonder if that makes a difference? I think issue is with signing, it thinks it is the same app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've seen the projects, the problem seems to be using jshybugger in all apps. However it requires that you specify unique authority name for each app i.e. the provider tag inside AndroidManifest.xml should be changed as follows and the app should be reinstalled:

```
<provider android:name="org.jshybugger.DebugContentProvider"
<!-- choose unique authority name for multiple apps on one device -->
android:authorities="my.package.name.jshybugger" ...
```

Comment: Tried that as well (I do actually use jshybugger), but still having issues. I will try removing it completely.

Comment: Removing it completely fixed the issue. But I wish I didn't have to delete it, as it is very inconvenient to install/uninstall it all the time...

Comment: Changeing  the authority name is possible since jsHybugger version 4.1 . If you are using AppBuilder or Cordova/Phonegap CLI the jshybugger authority name contains automatically the app package name to ensure authority name uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you need to have three different "Application Identifiers" - one for each app. You access this through the properties of your AppBuilder (Icenium) project.